# How to get out of boot loop on Mi 4i?

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, bootloader, xiaomi

I got stuck in a boot loop. Can access Mi Recovery. Can't access fastboot for more than 10 seconds. I had accidentally wiped everything from my phone, without any backup. Also, I had USB Debugging off in my device. Now, how do I flash a new ROM and reboot into my system?

Comment: Can you access mi recovery without connecting usb cable or charger?

Comment: No. In fact, the recovery crashes too, if I disconnect the charger.

Comment: So, I assume you can access recovery only by connecting a charger and no other functionality is accessible. If you disconnect the charger, it power off. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Sorry to reply so late. Now, what should I do?

Comment: check the answer. It is based on experience. after my experience, I adviced this to many people and almost 90 % will work

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking the same too. Will try that ASAP.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a million again Sagar. I'm in that 90%.

Comment: Consider marking it answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

**From Experience** : The problem is with your battery. The battery can't produce stable power.

When you go to recovery mode, the power consumption is very low. So, it will stay for some time.

When you turn on the phone, the brand logo is shown, may or may not the Booting is done. Suddenly the phone turns off. Then again turns on and repeat this automatically about 15-20 times.

I have the same issue and after checking for a weak , I found that the battery can't produce the power in a stable manner.

#### How to check.

Since your phone has an inbuilt battery, I am not suggesting you to remove cover, which may remove the sensor, then taking out the battery and doing so.

So, if the phone is under warranty, go to a service centre. Else, go to a local mobile mechanic and ask him to test the phone by putting an alternate battery.

80% it will work.

Try it and if you are in the 20% part, let me know.